# How to get TeXShop to ignore LaTeX commands when spell checking

Tags: mac, texshop, spelling

TeXShop is showing a spelling error (red dashed underline) for almost every LaTeX command. There must be a way to disable this so I can only check the spelling of my content.

Example screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Here: http://www.jkwchui.com/2010/03/spellchecking-latex-in-macosx/

Comment: @Sigur that worked perfectly!! Please add this as the answer so I can give you credit. Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Searching on Google I found [this](https://toeholds.wordpress.com/2010/03/21/spellchecking-latex-in-macosx/).

**Edited:** based on Sean's comment below I decided to insert here some caps from the original website to avoid broken links.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Just a note: link-only answers don't provide any security; if the linked website goes down, what happens then? I'd give a quick summary of the article here.

Comment: I don't know if this is helpful but the best place to look for this *was* in /Library/ (rather than ~/Library/). I don't remember the exact subdirectory. I basically did figure out how to compile and install a Welsh dictionary for cocoAspell with some fiddling. (Welsh was available but not for the right version of aspell hence it needed to be extracted and recompiled.) Once I got it right, it worked fine but I do remember having to fiddle somewhat and experiment a bit. The files in /Library/ helped to kind of reverse-engineer the process. This was on OS 10.4, though, so much may have changed.

Answer (score 1):

Note that it is possible that aspelle fail to compile dictionaries in Yosemite or El-Capitan. Then this link can be helpful:

https://tug.org/mactex/InstallingCocoAspell.pdf

Specially it is possible that you did not accept license agreement for Xcode which can be done via terminal and

`sudo make --version`

and entering the password when prompted, pushing space bar to pass through several pages and finally typing `agree` and hit enter.

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be to go to the **Apple Menu Bar**, select **Edit** and **uncheck** the spelling and grammar checks.
[image: depiction of what to uncheck]

Hope this Helps! :)