# Configuring TeXShop spell check to ignore citation?

Tags: texshop

I am using TeXShop on MacOS. I have configured the spell check to ignore latex commands following this advice: [How to get TeXShop to ignore LaTeX commands when spell checking](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151802/how-to-get-texshop-to-ignore-latex-commands-when-spell-checking)

But I want spell check to also ignore citations. For instance, I don't want spellcheck to say that "Irani2012" is a misspelled word b/c it is a cite (i.e. `\cite{Irani2012}`).

Is there an easy way to configure this?